# Verbal preference upon meeting people or meeting with others

Tags: грамматика

Is it correct to think that these mean the following and when would the sentences below the descriptions of each one of the verbs that I have be preferred to say? Why would one use a reflexive form of the verb? :

ВСТРЕ́ТИЛ - more general notion that includes meeting people for the first time, meeting up your friends, and just seeing someone without even talking at all.

ПОЗНАКО́МИМСЯ - to meet someone for the first time and talk a bit at least, to find out the person’s name and some other things you might be interested in

Я ВСТРЕ́ТИЛ твоего́ брата в метро́.

Мы ВСТРЕ́ТИЛИСЬ с твои́м братом в метро́.

Мы ВСТРЕ́ТИЛИ твоего́ бо́сса в го́роде.

Мы ВСТРЕ́ТИЛИСЬ с твои́м бо́ссом в торго́вом це́нтре.

Comment: Stefan, also note the verb натыкаться [наткнуться] на кого when you "run into someone" on the street, in the metro, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Literal meaning of `встречать` is to be on/by the way of someone/something, e.g. *встречать врага во всеоружии*. It relates to physical location of object. Reciprocal voice `встретиться` describes mutual process of physical relocation to the same location.

Literal meaning of `знакомить` is to give knowledge about subject and in reflexive form `знакомиться` is to obtain (give to him/her self) knowledge about subject.

Comment: I wish that I knew half of what you know about Russian!